# Trying to make a JQuery plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying something new for me.I am always making html pages with the same functions so I want to simplify my work using a JQuery plugin made by me.But this is the First time I am trying this and I  have read many web pages on how to do this and I don't know what doesn't work.This is
Emu.js file:

```
   $.fn.loop = function(time,callback) {
       setInterval(this,time);
       if(callback !== 'undefined' && typeof(callback) == "function") {
           callback
       }
   };
```

And this is Emu.html file:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <script src="JQuery.js" ></script>
       <script src="Emu.js" ></script>
   </head>
   <body onload="do_it()">
       <p></p>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           function hello() {
               $("p").append("Hello!"+"<br>")
           }

           function do_it() {
               $(hello).loop(2000)
           }
       </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: if you're trying to execute the callback you need to add the perens. `callback()`

Comment: `$(hello)` doesnt make any sense. `hello` is a function.

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle or codepen of your code ... A question,what are you trying to do in function do_it, it has a code as $(hello)

Comment: I am using $(hello) because in the Emu.js file I put setInterval with  _this_ and time parameters.So $(hello) returns the function hello as "this", isn't it?

Comment: `setInterval(this` doesn't make any sense..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- jQuery plugins/ Methods (just like `.show()`) expect a jQuery Element Object as reference: `$("p").loop()`
- Put the setInterval stuff within your `if`
- Use `$.proxy` to refer to the right jQuery `this` Element Object (otherwise `this` will point to `window` Object inside `setInterval`)
- Inside the `hello()` feel free to use jQuery's `$(this)` cause `this` refers to the JS reference on the HTMLParagraphElement `"p"`

```js
$.fn.loop=function(time,callback) {
  if(callback !== 'undefined' && typeof callback === "function") {
    setInterval($.proxy(callback, this), time);
  }
};


jQuery(function($) { // Use DOM ready instead of <body onload="do_it()">

  function hello(){
    $(this).append("Hello!<br>");
  }

  $("p").loop(2000,hello);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Some errors you've could avoid your self are i.e. the use of [WindowTimers.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) where the first parameter is supposed to be a callback `function` `setIntarval(fn, time)`. `this` is not a function in your case.